# Show that the joint function is a probability density using double integrals

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, expected-value, multiple-integral

**The question:**

Let $ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $0 < y \leq 1,  0 \leq x \leq y $. Assume that the distribution of the vector $(X,Y)$ is continuous with density 
$$ f(x,y)=\frac{1}{y} $$

is a probability density and then calculate the average vector and covariance matrix for the vector $(X, Y )$.

**The problem**
I solved the question but I feel that I have problems in:

1) is it enough to prove that function is a density by showing that the double integral = 1.

$2)$the  defining the limits of both integrals in each case among the three required cases

**The solution**

$*$ Now, integrating the function gives $1$ as

$\int_0^1 \int_0^y 1/y~ dx dy = \int_0^1 1 dy = 1$.

$*$ Following, to compute the mean vector, I used the formula: $E[<X,Y>] = < E(x) E(y)> ~$ where 
$E(X) = \int_0^1 \int_0^y \frac{x}{y}~ dx dy~ = \frac{1}{2}$ and $~ E(Y) = \int_0^1 \int_0^y \frac{y}{y}~ dx dy = \frac{1}{2}$

$*$ Finally, to compute the covariance matrix, it is necessary to find $\sigma^2(x), \sigma^2(y), cov(x,y)$.

$\sigma^2(x) = E(X^2)-E^2(X) = $ which are both calculated as above in the mean vector. For $cov(x,y) = E(XY) - E(X) E(Y)$ where $E(XY) = \int_0^1 \int_0^y \frac{xy}{y}~ dx dy = \frac{1}{6}$

**Sorry for taking long** Also, when computing the marginals they seem strange!
$f_Y(y)= \int_0^y \frac{1}{y}~ dx = 1 $ and $f_X(x)= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{y}~ dy = \log(1)- \log(0)$!

Comment: But what is $f(x,y)$?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel it is $=\frac{1}{y}$ for $(x,y)$ as defined above

Comment: A nonnegative function with integral = 1 is a density. The integrals are good but there is a problem in the formula for $E(X) = \int_0^1 \int_0^y \frac{x}{y}~ dx dy~ = \int_0^1 \frac{y^2}{2y}~ dy~ = \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @WNG Thanks a lot for help. Do the marginals look strange or not? I feel there is something wrong although I followed the definitions!

Comment: There is no need to find the marginal of $X$; it is clear from joint density that pdf of $Y$ is $f_Y(y)=1_{0<y<1}$ and conditional pdf of $X$ given $Y$ is $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)=\frac1{y}1_{0<x<y}$. This information is enough to calculate the moments ([law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) comes in handy if you are familiar with it).

Comment: Mention the support of the distributions while writing pdfs. We have $f_X(x)=\int f(x,y)\,dy=\int \frac1y1_{0<x<y<1}\,dy=\int_x^1\frac1y\,dy\,1_{0<x<1}=-(\ln x)1_{0<x<1}$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks a lot. It is clear now, I considered $0 \leq y \leq 1$

Comment: You can write an answer to your question (and accept it later) if you have solved the problem.